# delegate and the await task

Tags: c#, .net

creating method delegates and I ran into one problem:

```
D_AmortizationCalsAsync d_AmortizationCalsAsync = AmortizationCalsAsync; // here i have error

public delegate Func<Task<decimal>> D_AmortizationCalsAsync(int amortization, int installmentNumber);

public async Task<decimal> AmortizationCalsAsync(int amortization, int installmentNumber)
    {
      (...)
    }
```

Tak AmortizationCalsAsync (int, int) has a wrong return type

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0407?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0407)

Comment: `Func<>` should include the parameter types, not just the return type. It should be `Func<int,int,Task<decimal>>`. Why are you using a delegate though? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AmortizationCalsAsync` returns a `Task<decimal>`, not a `Func<Task<decimal>>`. If you want to assign it to delegate you need either change type of the delegate:

```cs
public delegate Task<decimal> D_AmortizationCalsAsync(int amortization, int installmentNumber);
```

Or use anonymous lambda to create a function with correct signature and return type (i.e. a function accepting 2 integers and returning a func with no parameters and `Task<decimal>` return type):

```
D_AmortizationCalsAsync d_AmortizationCalsAsync = 
    (a, i) => () => AmortizationCalsAsync(a, i);
```